# Does Django (w/ MySQL) do only 1 table lookup or multiple when counting with CASE

Tags: mysql, django, optimization, aggregate-functions, django-queryset

Lets say we have a model of the form

```
class Person(models.Model):
    is_gay  = models.BooleanField()
    is_tall = models.BooleanField()
    is_nice = models.BooleanField()
    ...
```

Now lets say we want to know how many people we have meeting different criteria. We can achieve this by counting them

```
num_gays = models.Person.objects.filter(is_gay=True).count()
num_tall_and_nice = models.Person.objects.filter(is_tall=True, is_nice=True).count()
```

Unfortunately, this would need 2 database queries. As you can imagine, as the number of types of people grows large, (e.g. an enumeration of 25/30) this can slow down quite a lot.

So now we can optimize by instead using aggregations

```
aggregations = {}

when = models.When(is_gay=True, then=1)
case = models.Case(when, output_fields=models.IntegerField())
sum  = models.Sum(case)

aggregations['num_gays'] = sum

when = models.When(is_tall=True, is_nice=Ttrue, then=1)
case = models.Case(when, output_fields=models.IntegerField())
sum  = models.Sum(case)

aggregations['num_tall_and_nice'] = sum    

result = models.Person.objects.aggregate(**aggregations)
```

However, I am curious as to how Django (using MySQL) processes this query.
**Does it look at the table only once, and each time it looks at a row, it adds `1` to every single CASE statement that applies. Or does it look at the table `N` times where `N` is the number of CASE statements?**

Comment: @Sayse I want 2 counts. 1 of all gay people and 1 of all people who are (tall AND nice). How would I achieve this then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this will be just one query. Because django Case/When more or less directly translates to mysql CASE/WHEN. However when in doubt you can always find out what queries have been executed by django using this bit of code

```
from django.db import connection
print connection.queries
```

Any query on and RDBMS without a where clause examines the full table. Every single one of the rows in your table will be looked at. This query doesn't seem to have a where clause.

But as for the number of queries that are executed. It's exactly 1

Comment: You misunderstand. I am asking when it gets to MySQL. How many times does MySQL look at the table. once or `n` times depending how many when statements

Comment: That's exactly what I have answerd. **once**

Comment: An addendum, will I have to worry about aggregations of the form `is_gay` and `is_gay and is_tall`, like will MySQL short circuit during WHEN statement of `is_gay` and forget about `is_gay and is_tall` or is it smart enough to handle this

Comment: it should be smaart enough.